# Query on Mac OsX

Tags: macos

I have a question to using some frameworks on Mac OSX.

For example, if events are to be obtained from Calendar application. This can be done using "CalCalendarStore" class. All the information related to Calendar can be obtained. But, does it leave any trace on the system that Calendar information has been queried?

Alternatively, the same information can be obtained parsing ".ics" files in the ~/Library/Calender/ directory. Does it leave any trace that information from calender application is queried too?

Thanks!!

Comment: I hope you have good reason for this question, it is not ok to read a users calendar without consent. Furthermore, there is no way you can ultimately hide this behaviour from a tracer/debugger.